How can I tell whether an HDD uses CMR or SMR?
I've recently read about conventional vs shingled magnetic recording on HDDs, and noticed that HDD models offered by the popular HDD vendors (WD, Seagate, Toshiba) don't seem to indicate whether they're SMR or CMR.
How can I tell which kind of recording strategy an HDD uses (hopefully without having that HDD at my disposal)? If the indication is vendor-specific, I'll take such answers, if you have them for any of the popular vendors.

This isn't an answer but a useful place to look would be somewhere like here  or here - and there's different flavours of SMR . Density could be a clue but I have a pair of 14tb drives with lots of platters and helium that are CMR. I might bounty a reliable non-lookup option

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352672/27961 also seems interesting

While a drive implementing host-aware or host-managed zones probably implies that it is an SMR drive, it doesn't mean that not implementing any of those (i.e., the zones are "drive-managed") implies that it is a CMR drive. See https://zonedstorage.io/docs/introduction/smr

Also sg3_utils is a set of SCSI utilities, whether any of them would work depends on the implementation of SCSI-ATA Translation Layer (SATL) in use (in addition to the support of corresponding ATA commands on the drive). When the drive is attached to a SATA/AHCI controller (well at least an onboard one), the SATL leveraged is implemented in the OS / kernel. When it's behind a USB/UAS bridge, it is implemented in the firmware bridge.
